# ASP.NET: NuGet/NuPack: Configuring location package files are put in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

Okay, so help me understand something here. I've got a new MVC solution and want to use NuGet to keep Modernizr up to date.

The problem is, NuGet puts the Modernizr scripts under ~/Scripts. This won't work--we've decided to put our JS in ~/js.

How do I modify the configuration of this package to tell NuGet that the Modernizr package should go in ~/Scripts or ~/Scripts/global instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this - I don't think this is functionality of NuGet, but rather the location of the scripts inside the NuGet package. This could vary from one package to another :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not a feature of NuGet, but it was mentioned in discussion on the [a NuGet forums](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/256542) including members of the NuGet team.  I don't see any work item that has officially been created for this yet, unfortunately. I performed [a quick search of the NuGet issues list](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic?field=CreationDate&direction=Descending&issuesToDisplay=Open&keywords=location&emailSubscribedItemsOnly=false) for the word "location" and didn't see one out there for this.  You might want to request it as a feature.